# 32 bits processor and partition size on SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I am looking for advice. I have just installed Ubuntu on my 1T SSD. I want to separate the OS from new data I will put there. I have a 32-bit processor: any advice or constraint on the size of the new partitions I will create for my data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Any advice"? That doesn't sound like a real question. What exactly are you asking? If you just want opinions it would be better to ask on the ubuntu forums or ubuntu discourse. Ask Ubuntu is a Q/A site, we don't do open ended questions or discussions. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33555/what-is-the-max-partition-supported-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the fact that you have a 32 bit processor will not affect the maximum size of your partitions.  As far as I'm aware, it only means that your system will not be able to use more than 4GB of RAM, which has nothing to do with hard disk partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot from a live USB or CD. 
Then try ro partition your disk with GParted as a usual HDD.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. I was just wondering if there is any restriction for the size of the partitions, since it is a 32 bits processor.

Comment: no. there isn't....

Comment: great, thanks! Just wanted to be 100% sure..